# Is there a way to disallow crawling of only HTTPS in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt, https

I just realized that Bingbot is crawling my company's website's pages over `https`.  Bing already crawls the site over `http`, so this seems frivolous.   Is there a way to specify `Disallow: /` for `https` only?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#About_the_standard), each protocol has its own robots.txt

And according to [Google's Robots.txt Specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), the `robots.txt` applies to `http` AND `https`

I don't want to `Disallow: /` for Bing totally, just over `https`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to serve both the site both in `http` and `https`? I would serve only `https` if it is available, and make permanent redirects from `http` URLs to `https` URLs.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Is "hasn't crossed our minds" a specific reason?  I'm going to put some thought into this, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to do it in *robots.txt* itself as served over HTTP.

You could serve a different robots file entirely for secure  HTTPS connections.  Here is one of doing so using rewrite rules in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots-deny-all.txt [L]
```

Where *robots-deny-all.txt* has the contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: I'd avoid doing this, though.  It may confuse the crawler into thinking that it should not crawl *anything* on your site, https or not.

Comment: No it wont Josh, this is fine. When you access robots.txt via https you get the different robots.txt as if you access it over http, as do web crawlers. I have used this method on many website.

Comment: @Chris: It is documented in [Google's robots.txt spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt). Under "Examples of valid robots.txt URLs:", you can see `http://example.com/robots.txt` is valid for `http://example.com/`, but not for `https://example.com/`. _"It is not valid for other subdomains, protocols or port numbers."_

Comment: Additionally, you can just serve a separate `robots.txt` for HTTPS requests like [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/63339/12183).

Answer (score 4):

Before you try to manipulate *robots.txt*, ensure that you have defined [canonical link elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) on your pages.

Web crawlers should treat:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="…" />
```

as a very strong hint that two pages should be considered to have the same content, and that one of the URLs is the preferred address for the content.

As stated in [RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) Section 3:

> The target (canonical) IRI MAY:
>
> …
>
> - Have different scheme names, such as "http" to "https"…

With the canonical link hints, a reasonably intelligent web crawler should be able to avoid crawling the site a second time over HTTPS.

Comment: Exactly this, and do note it's best to make the https canonical then. True, there is a very small overhead, but that seems hardly something to be worried about.

Comment: However, if you have a canonical link with http on a secure https page, wont there be a warning about an insecure element on the page? Might want to bare this in mind.

Comment: @Max Web browsers don't normally follow the canonical link.

Comment: But wont they still see the non-secure element in the page, then display the warning about some elements being insecure. The same as if you had images, js, etc on http?

Comment: I will have to try this, since there is some debate as to whether this would affect user's experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Add a *.htaccess* file to redirect HTTPS to HTTP, and to redirect requests for the *robots.txt* file to one that dissalows HTTPS crawling:

```
# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_https.txt
```

Then add a *robots_https.txt* with this in it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate *robots.txt* for HTTPS requests, for example: *robots_https.txt* and place this in the root of your website.

Then add the following lines to your root *.htaccess* file to redirect all bot requests over HTTPS to use *robots_https.txt* instead.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_https.txt
```

Comment: Is there any significant difference between this method and the answer that has `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on` ?

Comment: Same idea. @StephenOstermiller's technique is slightly better, in my opinion, as it avoids magic numbers.

Comment: No not really, one is based on HTTPS protocol and the other is based on server port for HTTPS. Both will work well in this instance. I'd probably be inclined to opt for StephenOstermiller's version as well.